# How to overlay circles on google map using Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, google-maps, flex4

i'm trying to show affected areas on city.

I want to use semi transparent circles to show the intensity of the effect by altering the radius of the circle and animate it while placing them. for example it appears as a dot and then grows to the intended size in fraction of a sec.

I could see some functions in javascript API but not in Flex. Saw some examples that uses polygon. But i dont want to plot all 360 points for just one circle.

is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Sprites as marker icons and animated them on frame enter

Comment: Hi Vivek Chandraprakash , can u please post a sample code for this .i need to create a circle overlay with border and fill color thanks

Answer (score 1):

To draw a circle you can use the FXG Ellipse primitive.  Here's more info on drawing shapes:  [Adobe Flex 4 * Shapes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS4D7543E0-0BA2-4f5f-92FA-985B6B6315AB.html)

Hope that helps.